# Can we have "drive" as a separate tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Recently, I have found myself asking questions about drives in general, such as flash drives or SD cards.  I want to use the `drive` tag, but whenever I try to use it, it's automatically changed to `hard-drive`.

Can we please have `drive` be a separate tag?

Comment: We already have [storage] as well as these specialized tags: [usb-storage], [sd-card]

Comment: Oh.  I was unaware.  Thank you!

Comment: @rahuldottech add that as an answer

Answer (score 7):

[drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drive) would be a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

We don't like meta tags because they require more information in the question or in other tags for them to be useful. They are rarely useful *on their own*.

For example: for your [drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drive), what kind of "drive", is it a USB drive, a floppy drive, a cd-rom drive, a hard disk drive or even an SSD?  All these things perform a similar basic function, but they function in *very* different ways.

For this reason is has been deemed necessary to force the issue and make "drive" point to something, in this case a [hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive), by making it a synonym. If you don't mean [hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) then you should delete it and use another more specific tag than [drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drive).

If you can't be specific enough about your problem to know what kind of drive is involved, or even *if* one is at all, then [drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drive) is not the tag you need.